# Using SWIG 2.0.4 with Ruby 1.9.2 to run the SWIG class example

Tags: c++, ruby, dll, swig

I'm just trying to use the ruby example that wraps a class from the SWIG library package. Here is what I did:

- Downloaded Ruby 1.9.2 for mswin32 from here: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/binaries/mswin32/
- Downloaded SWIG 2.0.4 from here: http://www.swig.org/download.html
- After converting the project file to MS Visual Studio 2010 and adjusting the paths I managed to compile the dll with the "example_wrap.cxx" file. It produced me a nice dll with just one exported initialize function. As far as I know that is perfectly normal.

The problem I have is I can't use the attached ruby script to link to the dll and use it. Here is the ruby file:

```
# file: runme.rb

# This file illustrates the C++ interface created by SWIG.
# All of our C++ classes get converted into Ruby classes.

require 'D:/Work/TUS_Work/temp/SWIG/class/example'

# ----- Object creation -----

print "Creating some objects:\n"
c = Example::Circle.new(10)
print "    Created circle #{c}\n"
s = Example::Square.new(10)
print "    Created square #{s}\n"

# ----- Access a static member -----

print "\nA total of #{Example::Shape.nshapes} shapes were created\n"

# ----- Member data access -----

# Set the location of the object

# Notice how we can do this using functions specific to
# the 'Circle' class.
c.x = 20
c.y = 30

# Now use the same functions in the base class
s.x = -10
s.y = 5

print "\nHere is their current position:\n"
print "    Circle = (", c.x, ",", c.y, ")\n"
print "    Square = (", s.x, ",", s.y, ")\n"

# ----- Call some methods -----

print "\nHere are some properties of the shapes:\n"
for o in [c, s]
  print "    #{o}\n"
  print "        area      = ", o.area, "\n"
  print "        perimeter = ", o.perimeter, "\n"
end
# Notice how the Shape#area() and Shape#perimeter() functions really
# invoke the appropriate virtual method on each object.

print "\n", Example::Shape.nshapes," shapes remain\n"
print "Goodbye\n"
```

The error I get after I run the ruby interpreter with this file as parameter is :

```
ruby.exe -I. runme.rb
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
D:/Work/TUS_Work/temp/SWIG/class/example (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from runme.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I created a example.rb file inside and that was "found" and loaded but the dll is not found even if I specify the full path and/or the file extension.

Did anybody else experience this problem and found a sollution ? I think that the reason is that ruby  version 1.9.x might have changed the api and lost compatibility with the old code, hence this is why this simple example does not work anymore. But I couldn't yet find the answer to this problem.

Comment: does D:/Work/TUS_Work/temp/SWIG/class/example.rb or D:/Work/TUS_Work/temp/SWIG/class/example.so exist?

Answer (score 1):

Require doesn't take a full path (or at least it isn't supposed to be used like this). Try it like this:

```
require 'example'
```

For Ruby to find the file, it looks in some predefined directories and directories specified via the `-I` command line option. You can inspect this by putting the following before  the require:

```
puts $LOAD_PATH
```

The directory where example is in should be listed, otherwise it won't be found. So try it with the following:

```
ruby.exe -I. -ID:/Work/TUS_Work/temp/SWIG/class runme.rb
```